# Rebuilt/ Being rebuilt/ Having rebuilt/Having been rebuilt?

Tags: sentence, passive-voice

I have a question and really need your help!

> _____ a short time after the civil war, Atlanta has become the principal centre of transportation and commerce and finance in the south-eastern US.

- A)    Rebuilt
- B)    Being rebuilt
- C)    Having rebuilt
- D)    Having been rebuilt

The answer is A, but why B, C and D are wrong? Can you explain to me?

Comment: B is the only one I find odd.  Of course, you failed to capitalize "Atlanta", and "center" is misspelled.

Comment: @Hot Licks: People on four continents would say "centre" is perfectly fine as is. We're outvoted.

Comment: @PeterShor - Not anyone in Atlanta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A) is correct.

(B) is wrong because it's present tense and the rest of the sentence is set in the past, so there's a tense mismatch.

(C) and (D) aren't really wrong, but without context they don't sound as good as (A) because there's no real need to use a perfect construction. If this was at the end of several sentences talking about the effects of General Sherman's destruction of Atlanta during the Civil War, I think (C) or (D) would sound fine.